# How use MediaFilePicker and PhotoEditor plugins in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, filepicker

I am trying to use MediaFilePicker on nativescript and at the same time use the PhotoEditor plugin to crop/edit the photo taken from the camera but I don't make it work... here is part of my code:

```
let options: ImagePickerOptions = {
    android: {
        isCaptureMood: true, // if true then camera will open directly.
        isNeedCamera: true,
        maxNumberFiles: 1,
        isNeedFolderList: true
    }, ios: {
        isCaptureMood: true, // if true then camera will open directly.
        maxNumberFiles: 1
    }
 };

 let mediafilepicker = new Mediafilepicker();
 mediafilepicker.openImagePicker(options);

 mediafilepicker.on("getFiles", function (res) {
 let results = res.object.get('results');
 let result = results[0];
 let source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
 source.fromAsset(result.rawData).then((source) => {
     const photoEditor = new PhotoEditor();
     photoEditor.editPhoto({
         imageSource: source,
         hiddenControls: [],
     }).then((newImage) => {            
     }).catch((e) => {
         reject();
         });
     });
 });
```

The result object of the FilePicker comes like:

```
{
"type": "capturedImage",
"file": {},
"rawData": "[Circular]"
}
```

I believe if the picture was taken from the camera, then use the rawData field, but I dont know which format is coming and how to give it to PhotoEditor pluging to play with it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Which platform you are facing the issue with?

Comment: I am testing on iOS, haven't tried Android yet.

Comment: Is it the photo editor never shows up? does it hit the catch block? Not sure why you have `reject();` again there, don't see any reference of a promise above.

Comment: I am using a Promise thats why. But the PhotoEditor never shows up.

Comment: Can you share a sample Git project where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Hi @Manoj, I have created an example so you can test: https://github.com/relez/ns-photo-ng.git. I hope it helps

Comment: Which device you are exactly using for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was at this line `source.fromAsset(result.rawData)` here, `result.rawData` is not an `ImageAsset` but it's `PHAsset`. You will have to create an `ImageAsset` from `PHAsset` and pass it on to `fromAsset`. So it would look like,

```
         import { ImageAsset } from "tns-core-modules/image-asset";

         ....
         ....
         imgSource.fromAsset(new ImageAsset(img)).then((source) => {
            const photoEditor = new PhotoEditor();
            console.log(source === imgSource);
            photoEditor.editPhoto({
                imageSource: source,
                hiddenControls: [],
            }).then((newImage: ImageSource) => {
                console.log('Get files...');
                // Here you can save newImage, send it to your backend or simply display it in your app

            }).catch((e) => {
                //reject();
            });
        });
```